# Files' hierarchy in pycharm leads to error

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

The attached image is to show the file hierarchy. No problem with the code. 
I'm trying to create a simple class testing but when I run post_test.py, I'm getting an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'post' 
I'm not sure what is wrong with the hierarchy of the files and why it cannot find the class.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in **post_test.py**, try **replacing**

`from post import Post`

with

`from blog.post import Post`